# Unwanted purple reflections on a reflecting surface

Tags: texturing, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, light

I'm trying to make a golden armor and use a tutorial to get the desired effect, but when I put it in the rendering view I get a purple glow. I have no idea  where the glow is coming from.

[image: Screenshot]

These are the settings that you use to obtain this effect:

[image: settings]

[image: settings]

For the hair, I did more or less the same procedure but also has the influence on, I do not know if that's the reason why I get that purple effect.

[image: Hair settings]

You could tell me why it looks like this and how I can fix it?

Comment: Hi. Please [edit] your question title so it is descriptive of the problem you are having, not just the general topic.

Comment: As this purple is a reflection, check lights and  environment: the material is not the responsible. Also remember that purple color is used as "alarm" of missing or not definied texture (Maybe a light texture or an environment one).